# ¿Como puedo leer los números de un archivo de texto para luego sacar un promedio?

Tags: c++

Necesito leer un archivo de texto y que a su vez calcule el promedio de números que se encuentren adentro del mismo, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

En mí código solamente puedo leerlos:

```
void Programa::leerMultiplos(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string lectura;
    int promedio=0, i=0, entero=0;;
    
    archivo.open("documento.txt",ios::in);
    
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(!archivo.eof()){
        getline(archivo,lectura);
        
        cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
        cout<<"=\t\tLeer y Mostrar Archivo\t\t="<<endl;
        cout<<"================================================="<<endl;
        cout<<"=\tInformacion del archivo:\t\t="<<endl;
        cout<<lectura<<endl;
    }
    
    
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un ejemplo del contenido del archivo?

Comment: si, es un documento txt, y tiene números sumados de 4 en 4, en el que estoy probando tiene "4 8 12" solamente con espacios

Answer (score 1):

Siendo que los números están en un archivo de texto, los podes leer de la misma forma que la entrada de la consola, mediante el operador [`>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Reescribiendo un poco el código, quedaría así:

```
int numero;
// ...
while(archivo >> numero){
    cout << numero << '\n';
}
```

Dentro del `while` podes hacer lo que necesites con los números. Ya sea sumarlos directamente o agregarlos a un vector.

Por ejemplo:

```
int suma = 0;
int cantidadNumeros = 0;
// ...
while(archivo >> numero){
    suma += numero;
    cantidadNumeros++;
}

float promedio = static_cast<float>(suma) / cantidadNumeros;
```

Cabe mencionar que el operador `>>` devuelve una referencia al objeto original . También existe una [conversión](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) que devuelve verdadero si no ocurrió ningún error de acuerdo a la tabla del enlace.

---

Por cierto, en esta línea `ios::in` es redundante.

```
archivo.open("documento.txt", ios::in);
```

[`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) es un stream de entrada y solo está preparado para lectura. Aunque usaras el modo `ios::out`, el archivo se abriría con el permiso correspondiente pero no podrías escribir en él porque la clase no lo permite.

Algo similar sucede con [`ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

Para más información, lee [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365984/13419694) de Stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono bastante este consejo, aunque todavía tengo otra duda y es acerca de como puedo mostrar una estructura, pero en este caso, una sola en especifico de varias almacenadas en el documento, ya que la cuarta opción de mi programa consiste en lo siguiente:

opción 4: Mostrar todos los datos de la estructura, en la cual se muestre el 
articulo con mayor cantidad en stock.

Comment: @Snow depende. Si está en binario es más fácil. Pero si está como texto también podés usar el operador >> del stream. Sería más cómodo si hicieras una pregunta nueva.

Comment: si, ya la he hecho

Comment: Si declaras `suma` como `float`, te ahorras tener que hacer la conversión al calcular el promedio.

Answer (score 1):

Sólo necesitas sumar los números y saber cuántos hay. Así que si en el bucle de lectura acumulas y cuentas, tendrás todo lo que necesitas:

```
std::stringstream datos("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1111");

float suma = 0;
int cantidad = 0;
for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
    suma += numero;
```

En el ejemplo he usado un flujo de datos de texto, puedes cambiarlo por un flujo de datos de archivo con el mismo resultado. Cuando tienes todos los datos simplemente muestra el promedio:

```
std::cout << cantidad << " numeros suman un total de "
    << suma << " y su promedio es " << (suma / cantidad);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDdisMgFISv41MMWSgJYdme/m/T5l1EbRESDf5clGWfPWtsuvXGw3eGGUcxjp93IabpQxvRR6lw0dYHp/jQsTfzL8S0CRi4NlXNfljhgzyf006b@1MByYP1VUnYYIsd9jjgiBO@QWsQgTagLWgH2oMOoCPoBErbdMq6Zay49ZYH@DhwXLFuWTEnCm6Cllwu6GYdqpmbOChnM30mt6jyja5bljVWKzTNy6FmRZHNm@simENzD2FjwOXyDktzuYh8fpFBNAg28B7pV8pklSTZLUsfacbo7KCktlA@ocSrLPj6t80tnQrRmbnM7zT9AQ)</kbd>.

---

Respecto al comentario:

> Gracias por responder, pero aun no comprendo mucho como estas empleando el bucle "for", o al menos con su lógica, no entiendo exactamente que quiere decir lo que tiene en los paréntesis, ya el comentario de arriba me funciono, pero de todas formas quiero aprender otro método por si las dudas

El bucle `for` que redacté está usando cuatro *trucos* del lenguaje C++:

1. Las variables declaradas en la primera parte del `for` sólo existen en el ámbito del bucle.

   ```
   for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
   //   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

   Dado que la variable sobre la que leemos sólo la necesitamos en el momento de leer, es adecuado que su ámbito esté limitado exclusivamente al bucle `for` de lectura. Que las variables existan en el ámbito lo más pequeño posible se considera una buena práctica.
2. Los flujos de datos son implícitamente convertibles a una expresión booleana.

   ```
   for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
   //                   ~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

   Al leer (o escribir) en un flujo de datos, éste puede quedar en un estado incorrecto (por ejemplo, por superar el final de los datos); un flujo de datos en estado incorrecto será evaluado como `false` si se usan en un contexto en que se espera un valor booleano.
3. El operador de lectura de flujo de datos (`operator >>`) devuelve una referencia al flujo del que se leyó.

   ```
   for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
   //                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ <-- devuelve 'datos'
   ```

   El paréntesis está por claridad, para indicar que `datos >> numero` es una operación diferente a `++cantidad` y para dejar claro que la operación no es `datos >> (numero && ++cantidad)`.
4. En lógica perezosa, al usar una condición *and* (`&&`) si el primer operando es `false` no se evalúa el segundo operando.

   ```
   for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
   //                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   // Si falla la opración 'datos >> numero', no se ejecuta '++cantidad'
   ```

En resumen, este bucle:

```
for (int numero = 0; datos; (datos >> numero) && ++cantidad)
```

Se interpreta de la siguiente manera: "*Usando `numero` como variable temporal, mientras `datos` sea verdadero (mientras `datos` esté en un estado válido) lee de `datos` en `numero` y si esa operación no falla (si `datos` permanece en un estado válido), incrementa `cantidad` en uno*".

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero aun no comprendo mucho como estas empleando el bucle "for", o al menos con su lógica, no entiendo exactamente que quiere decir lo que tiene en los paréntesis, ya el comentario de arriba me funciono, pero de todas formas quiero aprender otro método por si las dudas.